# Displaying points using Time property from geoJSON

Tags: openlayers, geojson

Can I do something similiar to what https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/wms-time.html accomplishes here but with geoJSON as my layer source?

I imagine I should be able to still read in the whole geoJSON file but only display the points if they match my time variable and then continuously call map.renderSync().

I'm just lost on how to implement it, or if there's only an example of WMS because I need to be able to query my dataset.